# Why are Comma's being printed when using explode?

Tags: php, explode

I have a string of names and I want to print them. I'm using the `explode` function. It works, however, my commas are being printed with the names and I don't want that. How can I make them not print? Any help is appreciated. Also how can I make my code more efficient?

```
$input = 'Jrew Low, Bill Wilt, Law Naw, Ing Holp';

list($fName, $lName, $fNameTwo, $lNameTwo, $fNameThree, $lNameThree, $fNameFour, $lNameFour) = explode(' ', $formInputNames);
if ($formInputNames == empty($fName) && empty($lName) || empty($fNameTwo) && empty($lNameTwo)){
    echo "No Valid Name";
} else {
// while ($fName == empty($formInputNames)){
//  echo "something is missing";
// }
echo "First Name: $fName <br> Last Name: $lName <br>";
echo "Email Address: $fName$email <br><br>";
echo "First Name: $fNameTwo <br> Last Name: $lNameTwo <br>";
echo "Email Address: $fNameTwo$email <br><br>";
echo "First Name: $fNameThree <br> Last Name: $lNameThree <br>";
echo "Email Address: $fNameThree$email <br><br>";
echo "First Name: $fNameFour <br> Last Name: $lNameFour <br>";
echo "Email Address: $fNameFour$email <br><br>";
}
```

Output:

> First Name: Jrew
>
> Last Name: Low,
>
> First Name: Bill
>
> Last Name: Wilt,
>
> First Name: Law
>
> Last Name: Naw,
>
> First Name: Ing
>
> Last Name: Holp

Comment: why are exactly 4 names? seems a very weird constraint. And.. can anybody have a second given name?

Comment: str_replace http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your separator in the explode function is " " (space). Why do you think the commas will disappear when you split the string from its spaces?

First split it by using

```
explode(", ", $input);
```

This will give you the list of the full names. Later you can split it once to get first name and last name separately:

```
explode(" ", $fullname);
```

But in my personal opinion, instead of binding all these names and surnames to different variables. Put them into an array and print the names by iterating over the array.

```
$input = 'Jrew Low, Bill Wilt, Law Naw, Ing Holp';
$fullnames = explode(", ", $input);

foreach ($fullnames as $fullname) {
    $nameSplit = explode(" ", $fullname);
    echo 'First Name: ' . $nameSplit[0];
    echo 'Last Name: ' . $nameSplit[1];
}
```

Comment: While this is a good explanation, please add your suggestion on how to fix it also

Comment: No green tick here yet. No comment from the OP neither, and that question's unclear also, given a comment below *"dones't work, it gets the commas gone but now the format of the output is all messed up. It's being read as FN: Jrew Low LN: Bill Wilt. – Ale"* - They're definitely not showing us the full picture here. Great answer though. Edit: *Finally*.

Comment: Perfect Answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are commas being printed? Because `explode` is splitting the string on the **spaces** - you didn't tell it to do anything with the commas.

Comment: While this is a good explanation, please add your suggestion on how to fix it also

Answer (score 0):

Change `explode(' ', $formInputNames)` to `explode(', ', $formInputNames)`

You are only splitting on spaces, but you want to also split on the comma to remove them.

Comment: don't forget he is echoing both first name and last name separately, using this doesn't give the required result

Comment: dones't work, it gets the commas gone but now the format of the output is all messed up. It's being read as FN: Jrew Low LN: Bill Wilt.

Comment: @Ale given what you posted for code, this does output the names minus the trailing commas. I for one have no idea what you mean by *"dones't work, it gets the commas gone but now the format of the output is all messed up. It's being read as FN: Jrew Low LN: Bill Wilt."*.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand the question.. this is the simplest way to do it..

```
$input = 'Jrew Low, Bill Wilt, Law Naw, Ing Holp';
$chunks = explode(" ", $input);
foreach($chunks as $index=>$name)
    echo ($index % 2 ? "Last" : "First") . " name: ".trim($name, ", ")."\n";
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://3v4l.org/0anmM)

Comment: Less lines is not "the simplest" way, this code is hard to read, especially for a beginner.

Comment: "simplest" is subjective.. the only thing confusing is the modulus operator.. and maybe the ternary